# In firefox5 css style sheet is not applying for elements

Tags: css, firefox-5

In firefox4 css class are applying for elements but in firefox5 no class is applied for elements.

In firebug of firefox5  i am getting "This element has no style rules. You can create a rule for it."

Point to note is that css style sheet is loading in header properly in firefox5.

Please  let me know to solve this problem....

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you're probably going to need to post some of your html and css to get any help with this.

Comment: my css works fine both in 4 and 5 versions. can you post some mo information

Comment: the web site at which this problem is happening is www.geoamida.com

Comment: How can you expect somebody to solve your problem when you didn't bothered to describe it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to take a wild guess and say that you should remove the charset declaration from the top of your CSS file.

Comment: thanks @charset "utf-7"; after removing this line form css style sheet this is working. and on googling aboy utf-7 i got "In order to comply with the HTML5 specification, support for the UTF-7 and UTF-32 character sets has been removed." https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Firefox_5_for_developers

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me while I was learning D3js. I solve the issues with

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML5>
```

At first I had it without the 5. After that all were solved.